# Flutter app with custom sign-in to firebase gets: FIRAuthErrorDomain, The custom token corresponds to a different audience

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I have a flutter app using custom sign-in (on iOS):

```
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCustomToken(token: customToken);
```

When I am connecting to my DEV Firebase project this works just fine.
I have now created a STAGING firebase project and downloaded the Google-Service.plist and trying to run my app against this project but get the following error on _auth.signInWithCustomToken(token: customToken) :

[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
PlatformException(Error 17002, FIRAuthErrorDomain, The custom token corresponds to a different audience.)

Research for this error is telling me that I'm using a plist file that doesn't match my STAGING firebase project - but its definitely the right one.
When I mint the custom token it is using a service account from the STAGING project as well.

Any idea what else could be the problem..?
Both my Firebase projects have iOS apps configured with the same bundle ID - is that an issue?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like the error message was right. Even though I have a script which copies the Google-Services.plist file into the correct place in my Xcode project it seems that Xcode still doesn’t recognise it. I have to manually drag and drop the file into place and then Xcode sets up the correct references. 
Seems that I need to use an Xcode build script and not just my own bash script to move these files around.

So we can put this one down to my lack of Xcode experience.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same issue. I tried manually dragging the Google-Services.plist file in manually from Xcode, without success.

What it turned out to be was that the service account deployed with the Firebase function was linked to a different environment.